# Unable to Find Solution: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1

Tags: javascript, api, http

I'm trying to build a basic React application that reaches out to an API to fetch quotes. The 'GET' request returns a string, however, when I try to parse that string to JSON is when I receive the error.

Here's my function making the request:

```
const httpCallout = () => {
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  const endpoint = "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1";
  Http.open("GET", endpoint, true);
  Http.send();
  let reply = "";

  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) =>{
      console.log(JSON.parse(Http.response));
      //console.log(Http.response);
  }
  return reply;
}
```

and the parsed response from the server:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1286,
    "title": "Adrian Shaughnessy",
    "content": "<p>Graphic design has been likened to a wine glass. When we drink wine we barely notice the glass it&#8217;s served in. It wouldn&#8217;t be true to say that we don&#8217;t care what glass we drink out of &#8211; we wouldn&#8217;t choose to drink a rare vintage out of a Tupperware mug, for example &#8211; but it&#8217;s the wine that matters, not the vessel it comes in.   </p>\n",
    "link": "https://quotesondesign.com/adrian-shaughnessy/",
    "custom_meta": {
      "Source": "<a href=\"http://observatory.designobserver.com/entry.html?entry=7257\">transcript</a>"
    }
  }
]
```

I'm also looking for non-jQuery responses. Again, the full error the console is throwing is: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` and giving the error at the line `console.log(JSON.parse(Http.response));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several things wrong here in your approach.

1.- It is not safe to make an "http" request because the browser will mark it as insecure, instead use https.

2.- The answer you receive is not valid to make a JSON.parse.

I would recommend this piece of cleaner code :)

```
fetch('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Comment: Wow, and it was that easy... Thank you so much for helping me out! I wish I had stumbled across fetch within the past few hours!

Answer (score 0):

read the docs for `onreadystatechange`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

The response will only be available if the readyState is set to 4, but the callback is executed multiple times (before the response has arrived).

To fix this, make sure you only do something with `response` when it's actually there.

Alternatively you might prefer the more untuitive new api for doing HTTP requests in browsers: `fetch()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API